# Qemu - substitute the init process

Tags: qemu, init

I have a couple of questions concerning qemu boot options

1)

When using the following argument

```
init=/bin/sh
```

It works - but is really the init-process replaced by a sh-process?

```
Qemu-system-x86_64 -hda output/images/rootfs.ext2 -kernel output/images/bzImage --append "root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0 rw init=/bin/sh" -serial stdio > /home/john/kernel_debug_mess.txt
```

2)

if I use the following option - the system cannot boot

```
 init=/bin/ls
```

the following error pops up in the kernel-logg:

```
 End kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init! exitcode 0x000000000
```

When using ls - how could the crash be explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.  When you tell the kernel to use `/bin/sh` as init, then it does exactly what you tell it to.
2. `/bin/ls` runs and then exits, so the kernel panics because there is no init process any more.  init is supposed to be a long-lasting process.